# Does Facebook "like" button differs from the URL with www and without it?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like

Does Facebook "like" button differs from the URL with www and without it?

If yes, how can I make it count for both urls? or how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it treats them as the same as long as they go to the same web content.

Examples:

https://graph.facebook.com/http://cocacola.com

https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.cocacola.com

Comment: Strange. Check those URLs: https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.scp.com.co (31 shares) --- https://graph.facebook.com/http://scp.com.co (1 share)

Comment: It's possible that at some time on that page, the og tags were setup to point to the www.scp.com.co and the other to scp.com.co which then started counting them as separate entities.  Just because now they look the same, doesn't mean at some point before they had separate web content

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test issues like these is to go here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

and input your URL.